# Searching for image samples in order to create custom classifier

Tags: computer-vision, object-recognition, face-detection, motion-detection, detection

I am training a classifier of my own, specifically for detecting body arms. According to the training process I have to provide positive samples and negative samples, wich will be used in the different stages of the cascade classifier. As Mathworks says [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/train-a-cascade-object-detector.html), there is a tradeoff between having a higher false positive rate(wich I think is good) and the training set size you have, so, if I want a high false positive rate, then I have to provide a lot of positive and negative samples. I don't expect to provide picture by picture and selecting ROIs(Region of Interest) hundreds of times manually, so my questions are:

- Is there any good repository of sample images for CV and specifically
  for body parts(I need arms specifically) different from [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cil/v-images.html).?
- Am I doing the right thing, or creating samples of my own is a better
  way to do this?

PD: **Remember: I am interested in having a high false positive rate**

Comment: False positive means the classifier tells you there's an arm even though there isn't one. Why would you want that?

Comment: @nikie: To work well, each stage in the cascade must have a low false negative rate. If a stage incorrectly labels an object as negative, the classification stops, and there is no way to correct the mistake. However, each stage may have a high false positive rate. Even if it incorrectly labels a nonobject as positive, the mistake can be corrected by subsequent stages.